# My question disappeared: is it bug or feature?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions

I asked question which was here: http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/1318648/what-tools-for-html-css-editing-do-you-prefer-and-why

When I refreshed it last time it has 2 votes to "close". But it has 2 answers and 2 comments and if it was deleted specially then it's very bad feature.

BUT, if it's a bug, then the TEST CASE is:

1. Create question
2. I don't know is it important but it had 2 answers, 2 votes for "close", one comment to the question and one my comment to the answer
3. Question was edited and saved 1 time (I dont think that it's important)
4. From the question I has created another question i.e. I clicked "Ask Question" not from main page but from my question
5. First question disappeared and the new question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318770/impressive-examples-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Was merged with another question as it is identical (dupe)

Comment: Then I think some kind of notification should be introduced because I don't know what's happend with my question, my comment and where to find them..